# React native ios deeplinking with universal URL

Tags: ios, react-native, react-navigation, deep-linking

I've been facing issue setting up deeplinking with react native for IOS with react navigation 5. 
When i try the URL scheme of `myownapp://homepage/` it opens up the app.

But if i try with url : `https://dev.myownapp.com/homepage/` it opens up the safari browser, but it doesnt open up the app.

I've tried with the documentation by adding Appropriate code in `AppDelegate.m` file and also ive added `myownapp.com` in the `Associated Domains` in **Xcode**.

[image: xcode]

Can you guys brief about what configuration is left to be done because the same opens in android. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you reach **https://dev.myownapp.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association** or **https://dev.myownapp.com/apple-app-site-association** yet?

If you can't, please host the file on the servers you want to be supported universal link.

**So to make it work:**

You need to setup your app to be supported wildcard domain by set **applinks:*.myownapp.com**.

You also need to host the config file (apple-app-site-association) to all the sub-domains, it means you're able to reach:

- *https://sub1.myownapp.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association*
- *https://sub2.myownapp.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association*
  ....

**Another thing you should notice that all your domains must be supported secure connection (https).**

Comment: The reason why it worked on android that to support wildcard domain for Applinks on Android, you just need to host the config file (assetlinks.json) on the root domain.

Comment: thanks for the answer, can you just brief what file needs to be hosted on the server?

Comment: Seems like you just set up the app to be supported deep link.
The thing you want to do called Universal link (iOS), Applinks (android).
For universal link you need to host the apple-app-site-association file that contains configuration json on the domain you want it to be worked.
In your case: https://dev.myownapp.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association or https://dev.myownapp.com/apple-app-site-association should work. More detailed: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/inter-process_communication/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/enabling_universal_links